# What is the term used for some kind of punishment

Tags: terminology, colloquialisms

What is colloquial word for kind of punishment for children/teen when he's not allowed to leave home (go to friends etc), but only school-home-school... ?

Comment: Ground the bastards. Scold them, lecture them for a while, and then ground them. That'll teach 'em.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use an adjective [***grounded***](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/grounded) as it means:

> (of a person, predicative) Confined to stay inside, typically by a
>   parent, as a punishment.

[Wiktionary]

> 1.1 informal (Of a parent) refuse to allow (a child) to go out socially as a punishment:

[[Oxford Online Dictionary]](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/ground?q=grounded#ground__23)

"You are grounded." means you are not allowed to go out to have fun.

Comment: "Campused" is another term that is occasionally used.  And other terms such as "confined to my quarters" may be used to give it a military sound (especially when a teen feels like his parents are acting like N*zis).